# DFS share empty when accessing it via domain name

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2, dfs

I set up a DFS to centralise my shares. After doing so, I noticed, that I can access the shares via the domain path (\\SNAKEOIL.LOCAL\Research), but the folders is shown as empty.

The intended namespace \\SNAKEOIL.LOCAL\Public is working as expected.

Why is that and how can I avoid this strange behaviour?

Servers are running Windows Server 2012 R2. Howevery, I have the same problem with 2008 R2, too.
Here is my setup:

> **SOIL-DC1 (domain controller, DFS)**
>
> - D:\Shares\Research (shared as \\SOIL-DC1\Research)
> - D:\Shares\Laboratory (shared as \\SOIL-DC1\Laboratory)
>
> **SOIL-DC2 (domain controller, DFS)**
>
> - D:\Shares\Development (shared as \\SOIL-DC2\Development)
>
> **\\SNAKEOIL.LOCAL\Public (DFS-Namespace)**
>
> - Research (targets to \\SOIL-DC1\Research)
> - Laboratory (targets to \\SOIL-DC1\Laboratory)
> - Development (targets to \\SOIL-DC1\Development)

Comment: Do you have permissions for all these folders? Windows will hide folders you don't have access to.

Comment: Will hide only with ABE enabled. But this is not the issue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens, when the DFS server is also a domain controller.